# Strange output of git diff to file in Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, command-line, diff

Ubuntu 13.04. I want to create a patch and there is no problem when I'm using Netbeans or other IDE but when I run in command line:

```
git diff > 1.patch
```

and then

```
cat 1.patch
```

output looks like this:

```
diff --git a/sites/all/modules/pet/pet.module b/sites/all/modules/pet/pet.module
index adfd273..1091090 100755
--- a/sites/all/modules/pet/pet.module
+++ b/sites/all/modules/pet/pet.module
@@ -71,7 +71,7 @@ function pet_access($op, $type = NULL, $account = NULL) {
 /**
  * Implements hook_permission().
  */
-function pet_permission() {  
+function pet_permission() {
   $permissions = array(
     'administer previewable email templates' =>  array(
       'title' => t('Administer previewable email templates'),
@@ -183,26 +183,26 @@ function pet_lookup_uid($mail) {
 /**
  * Send tokenized email to a list of recipients.
  *
- * Given a list of recipients, and an optional node id, perform token 
+ * Given a list of recipients, and an optional node id, perform token
  * substitution and send an email to each. The node substitutions, if any,
  * are the same in each email sent.  The user tokens, if any are custom based
- * on the account (if any) associated with each email.  
+ * on the account (if any) associated with each email.
  *
  * @param $name
  *   The unique name of the PET template.
  * @param $recipients
  *   An array of at least one recipient in one of two formats:
  *      1. a simple email address, in which case the uid is looked up
- *      2. an array('mail' => <email address>, 'uid' => <uid>) in which case 
+ *      2. an array('mail' => <email address>, 'uid' => <uid>) in which case
  *         the uid is already available (more efficient)
  * @param $options
  *   An array of options as follows:
  *      nid - An optional node id for token substitutions.
- *      subject - An optional subject which if provided will override the 
+ *      subject - An optional subject which if provided will override the
  *        subject in the PET.
  *      body - An optional body which if provided which will override the body
  *        in the PET.
- *      body_plain - An optional plain text body which if provided which will 
+ *      body_plain - An optional plain text body which if provided which will
  *        override the plain text body in the PET.
  *      from - An optional from email which if provided which will override the
  *        from in the PET (which in turn overrides the site default).
@@ -221,12 +221,12 @@ function pet_send_mail($name, $recipients, $options) {
     watchdog('pet', 'At least one recipient must be provided for PET %name.', array('%name' => $name), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
     return;
   }
```

but gedit shows this:

```
[1mdiff --git a/sites/all/modules/pet/pet.module b/sites/all/modules/pet/pet.module[m
[1mindex adfd273..1091090 100755[m
[1m--- a/sites/all/modules/pet/pet.module[m
[1m+++ b/sites/all/modules/pet/pet.module[m
[36m@@ -71,7 +71,7 @@[m [mfunction pet_access($op, $type = NULL, $account = NULL) {[m
 /**[m
  * Implements hook_permission().[m
  */[m
[31m-function pet_permission() {  [m
[32m+[m[32mfunction pet_permission() {[m
   $permissions = array([m
     'administer previewable email templates' =>  array([m
       'title' => t('Administer previewable email templates'),[m
[36m@@ -183,26 +183,26 @@[m [mfunction pet_lookup_uid($mail) {[m
 /**[m
  * Send tokenized email to a list of recipients.[m
  *[m
[31m- * Given a list of recipients, and an optional node id, perform token [m
[32m+[m[32m * Given a list of recipients, and an optional node id, perform token[m
  * substitution and send an email to each. The node substitutions, if any,[m
  * are the same in each email sent.  The user tokens, if any are custom based[m
[31m- * on the account (if any) associated with each email.  [m
[32m+[m[32m * on the account (if any) associated with each email.[m
  *[m
  * @param $name[m
  *   The unique name of the PET template.[m
  * @param $recipients[m
  *   An array of at least one recipient in one of two formats:[m
  *      1. a simple email address, in which case the uid is looked up[m
[31m- *      2. an array('mail' => <email address>, 'uid' => <uid>) in which case [m
[32m+[m[32m *      2. an array('mail' => <email address>, 'uid' => <uid>) in which case[m
  *         the uid is already available (more efficient)[m
  * @param $options[m
  *   An array of options as follows:[m
  *      nid - An optional node id for token substitutions.[m
```

.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's colorized. `<kbd>Esc</kbd>[36m` is an ANSI escape sequence for a foreground color change.

#### 1. Disable color

```
git diff --color=never
```

#### 2. Or change the config

```
git config color.ui auto
```

This results in `.git/config` having:

```
[color]
    ui = auto
```

`auto` indicates that color is automatically enabled when output is to a terminal, but not if output is to a file/pipe.

#### 3. Fixing existing patches

Look at [AnsiFilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/zip/download.html) to remove ANSI escape sequences from existing patch files.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I've used 1st option and got a correct patch.

Comment: Then I've checked my config and found [color] diff = always and ui = true. I removed 'diff = always' and set 'ui = auto' as you've suggested and got correct patch and colorized git diff output! Thanks again you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

I follow this link [enter link description here](http://excid3.com/blog/how-to-fix-esc-in-your-terminal/) to see color:

$ export LESS="-eirMX"

You may need to edit **.profile** or **.bashrc** to permanently set environmental variables. For straight forward, all you need to do is to append the above line to one of the 3 following files:

```
~/.profile
~/.bash_profile
/etc/profile
```

Comment: I found the `-R` is required for macOS, which is different from `-r`.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try, it worked for me:

```
git config --global color.diff auto
```